# Rest-API not responding in the intended way

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, backend

I was learning to build a Rest-API from [Acadmind](https://www.youtube.com/@academind) but I'm facing a minor issue, I was expecting my API to return the **name** & **price** that are passed to it in the POST request. However, it is just returning me the objectId of that particular request.
(I have installed body-parser).

I'm attaching the code, please comment if you need any additional module for correction

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Product = require('../models/product');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

router.get('/', (req, res, next) =>{
    res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Handelling GET requests to /products'
    });
});

router.post('/', (req, res, next) =>{
    const product = new Product({

        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        name: req.body.name,
        price: req.body.price
      });
      product.save()
      .then(result =>{
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch(err => {console.log(err)});
    res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Handling POST requests to /products',
        createdProduct: product
    });
});



router.get('/:productId', (req, res, next) =>{
    const id = req.params.productId;
    if(id === 'special'){
        res.status(200).json({
        message: 'You discovered the special id',
        id: id
    });
    }   else {
        res.status(200).json({
            message: 'You passed an id'
        });
    }
});

router.patch('/:productId', (req, res, next) =>{
    res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Updated Succesfully'
    })
});
router.delete('/:productId', (req, res, next) =>{
    res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Deleted Succesfully'
    })
});

module.exports = router;
```

and the module where I have my data Schema is below

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, //This is a long alphanumeric format mongoose used internally
  name: String,
  price: Number
  
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

Below, is my main module

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.use((req, res, next)=>{
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   //* means we are providing access to all the origins, we can also restrict this by giving some 
   //specific URL's in place of *

   res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
    //line 12 and 13 provides all the possible headers that might be sent along with the requests
    //line 13 is some of the possible headers
   ); 
   if(req.method === 'OPTIONS'){
    // req.method === OPTIONS checks for the OPTIONS of the req made ie OPTIONS is sent by the browser
    // to check if the request is safe to send or not
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET');
    return res.status(200).json({});
   }
   next();
});

const productRoutes = require('./api/routes/products');
const orderRoutes = require('./api/routes/orders');

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.eslpnrq.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {useNewUrlParser: true}
);

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/products', productRoutes);
app.use('/orders', orderRoutes);


app.use((req, res, next)=>{
    const error = new Error('Not Found');
    error.status = 404
    next(error);
})
app.use((error, req, res, next) =>{
    res.status(error.status || 500);
    res.json({
        error: {
            message: error.message
        }
    });
});

module.exports = app;
```

Again, please feel free to ask for any additional module/code fragment.

I have tried enough on my end, but cannot find my mistake. I have attached the screenshot of postman below

[image]

Alongside objectId, it should also return the name and price passed to it in POST request.

Comment: in postman shouldnt you send the request in raw JSON

Comment: As per @cmgchess select json (not text) in the raw body for the Postman call. If that doesn’t fix add console.log(‘req.body’, req.body); console.log(‘product’, product); above res.status(201).json({ and add the console log to the question.

Comment: You should wait this 'product.save()' promise before send response

Answer (score 0):

Change your schema price:Number --> price:String, and *_id* is automatic:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  price: String  
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

And check if req.body is not undefined adding a console.log:

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) =>{
    console.log(req.body);
    const product = new Product({
        name: req.body.name,
        price: req.body.price
      });
      product.save()
      .then(result =>{
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch(err => {console.log(err)});
    res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Handling POST requests to /products',
        createdProduct: product
    });
});
```